Testlink integration with bugzilla/ After test case execution create issue is not working
I deployed Bugzilla and Test link in Docker. I created an issue tracker in Test link for Bugzilla, this is the configuration:
<issuetracker>
<username>username</username>
<password>Password</password>
<dbhost>host</dbhost>
<dbname>name</dbname>
<dbtype>type</dbtype>
<dbuser>user</dbuser>
<dbpassword>password</dbpassword>
<uribase>http://localhost:80/</uribase>
<product>BUGZILLA_PRODUCT</product>
<component>BUGZILLA_COMPONENT</component>
</issuetracker>

I need to confirm that Bugzilla is integrated with Test link successfully. So, I executed some sample test cases in Test link. After execution, in the Bug Management section, I tried to Link Existent Issue or Create an Issue in Bugzilla. It throws an error like this:
Fatal error: Uncaught Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception: Unable to Connect to http://localhost:80. Error #32659: Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in /var/www/html/third_party/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php:235 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/third_party/Zend/Http/Client.php(1059): Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->connect('http://localhos...', '80', false) #1 /var/www/html/third_party/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php(280): Zend_Http_Client->request('POST') #2 /var/www/html/third_party/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php(372): Zend_XmlRpc_Client->doRequest(Object(Zend_XmlRpc_Request)) #3 /var/www/html/third_party/Zend/XmlRpc/Client/ServerProxy.php(93): Zend_XmlRpc_Client->call('system.methodSi...', Array) #4 /var/www/html/third_party/Zend/XmlRpc/Client/ServerIntrospection.php(146): Zend_XmlRpc_Client_ServerProxy->__call('system.methodSi...', Array) #5 /var/www/html/third_party/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php(315): Zend_XmlRpc_Client_ServerIntrospection->getMethodSignature('User.login') # in /var/www/html/third_party/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php on line 235

What can I do to solve this?

Which part(s) of this are in containers?  Can you [edit] the question with more details of how you're starting those containers?  (What is localhost in this question?)
